# Getting rid of hddtemp prompt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any option to get rid of the `hddtemp` prompt or automate the response?

I followed the [standard ROS hydro installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu) and ran `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full`, and the `hddtemp` prompt comes up. Is there a standard way to automatically answer no to this question so that I don't have to 'babysit' every computer that I install ROS on?

Thanks,
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191042/getting-rid-of-hddtemp-prompt/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-23**:
This isn't really ros-related; that prompt is coming from the hdtemp package. You may want to consult the dpkg and apt manuals or ask on a Debian or Ubuntu forum.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-23**:
That said, I remember being able to do this when I built the PR2 installer, but I don't remember the esoteric invocation that I needed to make it work properly, and I don't remember if it was something that I set in the preseed file or some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer (ironically) is on the [ROS PR2 installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/PR2/hydro). It is to do with the Ubuntu package installation. The command is:

`echo "hddtemp hddtemp/daemon boolean false" | sudo debconf-set-selections`

See the page for full context.

I am in two minds. It's not a ROS problem in the sense that it's not a ROS package that is interrupting the automated setup process, on the other hand it is a ROS problem because it affects a ROS.

---

Originally posted by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) with karma: 163 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0